# No Ubuntu touchscreen driver

Tags: touchscreen, 20.10

So I have been looking for drivers for CMN1406 monitor. Last week my Touchscreen stopped receiving inputs. It still displays. I have searched for this CMN1406 driver, but I couldn't find one.

Edit: My laptop is a Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5. I am currently running on a dual-boot machine with windows 10 running side by side. The problem is that Windows touchscreen works, while ubuntu does not work

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for the right product? The only reference I can find (https://www.panelook.com/N140HCA-E5B_Innolux_14_LCM_parameter_46535.html) says it doesn't have a touch screen (look at the summary at the end of the page). However, if it worked a week ago, there obviously were drivers present. Did you maybe install a new kernel since then? Also, how is the screen connected to your computer?

Comment: Hi! So I have been using a laptop for Ubuntu 20.10. I have been updating my kernel from 5.4 to 5.9.1. I had installed ubuntu and I updated to 5.9.1.

Edit: I am using a Lenovo, if that helps

Comment: So you are talking about the built-in display of your laptop? Please add the exact model number of your laptop to your question, as well as the other information from your last comment.

Comment: My laptop is a Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5. I am currently running on a dual-boot machine with windows 10 running side by side. The problem is that Windows touchscreen works, while ubuntu does not work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all of that information to your question. Has it ever worked on Ubuntu?

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: I still have not found the touchscreen driver...